# IZPack Setting Linux Environment Variables

Tags: linux, environment-variables, izpack

I am sure this has to be out there somewhere, but after about a day of searching I am stuck.  I am trying to use IZPack to do an installation on Linux and trying to call a shell script that sets some environment variables.  However I don't know how to "source" the script instead of just running it.  Running the script using:

```
<executable type="bin" stage="postinstall" targetfile="$INSTALL_PATH/myscript.sh" os="unix"/>
```

This only executes the script, it does not source it.  So all exports of ENV variables are lost once the script completes.

How can I source my scripts from IZPack instead of just running them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO you simply cannot influence the shell environment your Java process of your IzPack installer is running in from that process itself.

Answer (score 1):

Torsten is right. This is not an issue of IzPack, Java or anything else, this is just the way operating system process work with respect to environment variables ;-)